# Cypher Query to find aggregated sum of connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to come up with a suitable Cypher query on the following dataset:

```
Joe --> Hotel1 (connnection score is 1)
Blogg --> Hotel1 (connnection score is 1)
Joe --> Hotel2 (connnection score is 1)
Blogg --> Hotel2 (connnection score is 1)
```

I want to be able to aggregate the connections score and say Joe & Blogg have a connection score of 2 (Hotel 1 score + Hotel 2 score).

Joe, Blogg, Hotel1, Hotel2 are modelled as nodes and --> means "STAYED_IN".

I'm not really interested in knowing which hotels they stayed. I'm only interested in finding the scores between 2 persons considering all the commonly intersecting hotels between them.

Answer (score 0):

If there is at most one connection between each person and hotel you could use

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-->(h1:Hotel)<--(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.name>=p2.name
WITH DISTINCT p1,p2
MATCH (p1:Person)-[c1]->(h1:Hotel)<-[c2]-(p2:Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name, SUM(c1.score+c2.score)
```

assuming your graph has the following form:

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Joe'})
CREATE (p2:Person {name: 'Blogg'})
CREATE (h1:Hotel {name: "Hotel1"})
CREATE (h2:Hotel {name: "Hotel2"})
CREATE (p1)-[:stayed_in {score: 1}]->(h1)
CREATE (p2)-[:stayed_in {score: 2}]->(h1)
CREATE (p1)-[:stayed_in {score: 1}]->(h2)
CREATE (p2)-[:stayed_in {score: 1}]->(h2)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd want to use the "score" property in the connection than a count. Every connection to a hotel will have a "score" property in it. Finally I want the sum of scores between 2 persons considering all hotels they stayed together.

Comment: In case you have at most one connection per person-hotel combination, the answer is a simple modification. I changed that in the answer for that case. If, however, you have multiple connections, the code above will double count some of the scores, and one has to work a little more to remove that.